# Why can't I stop background-repeat: from repeating?

Tags: css

I am having a bizarre issue.  In the spirit of trying to write DRYer, shorter code, I want to remove 'no-repeats' from my individual h3 styles and do it with just one declaration.  Below is an example version of the code that fails.   The h3 in #c stubbornly will not stop repeating unless I set it as I did for #a and #b.
I have tried replacing background-repeat:none with :no-repeat, but no luck.  Thanks in advance for any assistance!

```
.class > h3
    {   
        float:left;
        height:21px;
        width:200px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }

    #a > h3 {background:url(a.png) no-repeat;}
    #b > h3 {background:url(b.png) no-repeat;}
    #c > h3 {background:url(c.png);}

    /* EDIT: this code does not work (even after applying Thom's answer)    
    h3 {background-repeat:none;}
    */

    h3 {background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`background` is a shorthand declaration that sets a number of values. It's overriding your declaration of `background-repeat`. Replace `#c > h3`'s `background` declaration with `background-image` instead.

Comment: Well that cleared everything right up!  Thank you Thom.  I had a feeling it was something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

> Why won’t background-repeat:none work?

Because it's named [`no-repeat`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) :)

Comment: Did you read the question? 'I have tried replacing background-repeat:none with :no-repeat, but no luck' or do you mean {no-repeat:none} or something like that?  I took the background-repeat:none from within Paul Irish's http://html5boilerplate.com/ css file so it must have some use.

Comment: background-repeat:none works fine now that I implemented Thom's answer.   Maybe my next question should be "why DOES background-repeat:none work?" lol.

Comment: Seems as though w3 schools css reference agrees with you however. http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-repeat.asp.  Now I don't know which one to use :-(

Comment: @Zach nope, I didn't read closely enough, sorry. Will delete soon

Comment: @Pekka no wait stop! lol! you were right.  The version of code I fixed with Thom's code had :none not :no-repeat.  I just tried changing this and it broke.  +1 for my ignorance.

Comment: Regardless of if 'none' works or not, I'll remove it from the boilerplate. Not sure how that nastiness made its way in. Thx

Answer (score 0):

OK, **background-repeat:none** it is not a valid property. You have **repeat**, **no-repeat**, **repeat-x**, **repeat-y** and **inherit** which inherit property from the parent element but **none** doesn't exist. Maybe it'll work with browsers like Chrome and Firefox that try to figure out what you meant but IE is very picky with this things.